# Get max ID and min ID from specific column in MySQL php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm new to `php` and now trying to retrieve the data from `MySQL` to android.

This is my **work_details** table

[image]

In **RetrieveTotalHours** function, I want to retrieve the **min id time-in** and **max id time-out** from `MySQL` to android through `php` and finally use the code below to get the total hours.

Assume the ID is 3 , so I want to  get the **timeIn** where `id=3`, **timeOut** where `id=25`. This is what I've tried so far.

```
  public void RetrieveTotalHours( final String ID) // ID(twd)=3
    {
        class GetHours extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Fetching...","Wait...",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                showHours(s);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequestParam(Configs.RETRIEVE_HOURS,ID);
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetHours ge = new GetHours();
        ge.execute();

    }
    private void showHours(String json) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Configs.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
            String MiNtimeIn = c.getString(Configs.TAG_IN); 
            String MaXtimeOut=c.getString(Configs.TAG_OUT);

            long difference = 0;
            if (MiNtimeIn > MaXtimeOut) {
            difference = (MaXtimeOut + (24 * 60) - MiNtimeIn) - (1 * 60);
            minutes = (int) (difference % 60);
            hours = (int) ((difference / 60) % (24 * 60));
            totalHours.setText(("Total hours : " + hours + ":" + minutes));

           } else {
            // .....
          }

            total.setText(hours);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Retrieve_hours.php**

```
<?php
  define('HOST','127.0.0.1:3307');
  define('USER','root');
  define('PASS','');
  define('DB','androiddb');

  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect');

  $twd= $_GET['id'];

 $sql = "select timeIn, timeOut from work_details WHERE twd = '".$twd."' AND id IN
 (SELECT MIN(id) FROM work_details WHERE twd ='".$twd."' UNION SELECT MAX(id) FROM work_details WHERE twd='".$twd."')";

  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $result=array();


  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result,array('id'=>$row[0],'timeIn'=>$row[1],'timeOut'=>$row[2]));
  }

 echo json_encode($res);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**Configs**

```
    public static final String TAG_IN="timeIn";
    public static final String TAG_OUT="timeOut";
```

**Error**

```
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_WorkDetails.showHours(Edit_WorkDetails.java:248)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_WorkDetails.access$000(Edit_WorkDetails.java:46)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_WorkDetails$1GetHours.onPostExecute(Edit_WorkDetails.java:232)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_WorkDetails$1GetHours.onPostExecute(Edit_WorkDetails.java:220)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
01-10 19:31:47.355    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
01-10 19:31:47.360    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 19:31:47.360    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-10 19:31:47.360    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
01-10 19:31:47.360    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
01-10 19:31:47.360    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 19:31:47.380    1298-1298/com.example.project.myapplication D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
```

**Edited**

[image]

```
 String MiNtimeIn = c.getString(Configs.TAG_IN); 
 String MaXtimeOut=c.getString(Configs.TAG_OUT);
```

Assume the ID(twd) is 8, I should get 21:52 in timeIn and 1:52 in timeOut.
MiNtimeIn should display 21:52(id 3), MaXtimeOut should display 1:52(id 4)

Comment: if you get correct value, you are OK.

Comment: @GoudaElalfy I get `W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@John`,

Check my answers about this errors:

- [`How do I solved java.lang.String cannot converted to JSON object?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481394/how-do-i-solved-java-lang-string-cannot-converted-to-json-object/34513561#34513561)
- [`org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML><HEAD><STYLE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21976643/1880431)

---

Here us the issue:

```
echo json_encode($res);
```

You are encoding the `$res` variable.

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

`mysqli_query()` returns a `mysqli_result` object.

It is the resultset, you cannot `encode` them into `JSON`.

You need to fetch it to a `PHP` array first like you did in the loop.

You did not use that array for the `JSON` encoding so `echo json_encode($res);` is not correct it should have been `echo json_encode($result);`

You can also simplify this code:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

---

This error is because you are trying to parse it as a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

It should be a json array:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
```

Comment: what exactly did you want

Comment: sir can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068372/get-error-when-trying-to-send-new-password-to-e-mail-by-php

Comment: @JohnJoe yeah I posted

Answer (score 2):

replace this section:

```
$result=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result,array('id'=>$row[0],'timeIn'=>$row[1],'timeOut'=>$row[2]));
}
echo (json_encode(array("result"=>$result)));
```

with:

```
echo json_encode($res);
```

you create a  lot of arrays, when you make push in while loop you push array in $result array, then when you echo you put all results in another array. and this is more complex.