# Get min ID and max ID value in MySQL php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I wonder how to get the **timeIn** which has the min id and **timeOut** which has the max id from `MySQL` php to android ?

This is table work_Details(id,project,percentage,timeIn,timeOut,twd). Now I want to retrieve the `timeIn : 12:26:00` and `timeOut 11:26:00`

[image]

```
  public void RetrieveTotalHours( final String ID)  // Assume ID is 69
    {
        class GetHours extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Fetching...","Wait...",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                showHours(s);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequestParam(Configs.RETRIEVE_HOURS,ID);
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetHours ge = new GetHours();
        ge.execute();

    }
    private void showHours(String json) {
        try {
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray(json);
            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(array.length()-1);
            String MiNtimeIn = jsonObject.optString(Configs.TAG_IN);
            String MaXtimeOut=jsonObject.optString(Configs.TAG_OUT);
            Log.e("A",MiNtimeIn);
            Log.e("S", MaXtimeOut);
            //total.setText(MiNtimeIn);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**php**

```
<?php
  define('HOST','127.0.0.1:3307');
  define('USER','root');
  define('PASS','');
  define('DB','androiddb');

  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect');

  $twd= $_GET['id'];

 $sql = "select timeIn, timeOut from work_details WHERE twd = '".$twd."' AND id IN
 (SELECT MIN(id) FROM work_details WHERE twd ='".$twd."' UNION SELECT MAX(id) FROM work_details WHERE twd='".$twd."')";


  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $result=array();

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result,array('timeIn'=>$row[0],'timeOut'=>$row[1]));
  }

 echo json_encode($result);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**Wrong Output**

```
01-12 12:43:41.540  22692-22692/com.example.project.myapplication E/A﹕ 20:26:00
01-12 12:43:41.540  22692-22692/com.example.project.myapplication E/S﹕ 11:26:00
```

It retrieves the timeIn and timeOut which has the max id...

Comment: Which logic u want to implement to retrieve `timeIn : 12:26:00 and timeOut 11:26:00` values ? because u are getting two rows from db and u want to use `timeIn` from first row and `timeOut ` from second row right?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Exactly.. is it possible to achieve  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> retrieves the timeIn and timeOut which has the max id...

Do it as to get `MiNtimeIn` from First JSONObject and `MaXtimeOut` from second JSONObject:

```
String MiNtimeIn,MaXtimeOut;
JSONArray array=new JSONArray(json);
if(array.length()<2){
  JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(0);
  MiNtimeIn = jsonObject.optString(Configs.TAG_IN);
  MaXtimeOut=jsonObject.optString(Configs.TAG_OUT);
}else{
  // get First Object from JSONArray
   JSONObject oneObject = array.getJSONObject(0);
  MiNtimeIn = oneObject.optString(Configs.TAG_IN); // get min from first row
  // get Second Object from JSONArray
   JSONObject twoObject = array.getJSONObject(array.length()-1);
   MaXtimeOut = twoObject.optString(Configs.TAG_OUT); // get min from second row
}
```

Comment: If I don't want to fix the array.length, what should I do ?  Assume the number of row does not fixed

Comment: @JohnJoe: if number of row not fix then you need a develop a logic for selecting `TAG_IN ` and `TAG_OUT ` and currently in my answer logic is : if single row found then it will show both for that row otherwise show TAG_IN from first row and  TAG_OUT from last row.

Comment: If I have 100 row, your answer still can use right ?

Comment: @JohnJoe: you tell if you have 100 rows then what you want ?

Comment: Get the timeIn from 1st row and timeOut from last row sir

Comment: Do I need to change anything in php ?

Comment: @JohnJoe: no need to change in PHP