# Get error when trying to send new password to e-mail by php

Tags: php, android

I'm a beginner of `php` and now getting stuck on sending a new password to user e-mail if user requested in `android`.

**ForgetPassword.php**

```
  <?php 
require_once('DB_Functions.php');
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $forgotpassword = $_POST['forgotpassword'];

    $randomcode = $db->random_string();
    if(isset($_POST['forgotpassword'])){
       $hash = $db->hashSSHA($randomcode);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"];
        $subject = "Password Recovery";
        $message = "Hello User,nnYour Password is sucessfully changed. Your new Password is $randomcode . Login with your new Password and change it in the User Panel.nnRegards,nLearn2Crack Team.";
        $from = "contact@learn2crack.com";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
     if ($db->isUserExisted($forgotpassword)) {

     $user = $db->forgotPassword($forgotpassword, $encrypted_password, $salt);
      if ($user) {
         $response["success"] = 1;
          mail($forgotpassword,$subject,$message,$headers);
         echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else {
       $response["error"] = 1;
      echo json_encode($response);
        }
     }

            // user is already existed - error response

        }
           else {

            $response["error"] = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User not exist";
             echo json_encode($response);

}

?>
```

**DB_Functions.php**

```
    <?php
 require_once('dbConnect.php');
class DB_Functions {

    private $db;


    /**
     * Random string which is sent by mail to reset password
     */

public function random_string()
{
    $character_set_array = array();
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 7, 'characters' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 1, 'characters' => '0123456789');
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach ($character_set_array as $character_set) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $character_set['count']; $i++) {
            $temp_array[] = $character_set['characters'][rand(0, strlen($character_set['characters']) - 1)];
        }
    }
    shuffle($temp_array);
    return implode('', $temp_array);
}

  public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
        if($result)
        {
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            // user existed
            return true;
        }
        }else {
            // user not existed
            return false;
        }
    }


 public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

public function forgotPassword($forgotpassword, $newpassword, $salt){
    $result = mysqli_query("UPDATE `users` SET 'password` = '$newpassword'
                          WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'");

if ($result) {

return true;

}
else
{
return false;
}
}
}
?>
```

**dbConnect.php**

```
<?php
    define('HOST','127.0.0.1:3307');
    define('USER','root');
    define('PASS','');
    define('DB','androiddb');

    //Connecting to Database
    $con= mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
?>
```

This is what I have tried so far, unfortunately it gives me a bunch of error ! Any help would be appreciated .

I get tutorial from [here](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/08/develop-android-login-registration-with-php-mysql.html/4).

**Error**(latest)

> Notice: Undefined index: forgotpassword in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Android\CRUD\forgetPassword.php on line 4
>   {"error":2,"error_msg":"User not exist"}

Comment: It is unwise to send passwords in an email; use a reset function and generate a one-time secure link. I can't spell out how here, but there is plenty of information out there.

Comment: The answers you seek are in the error messages.

Comment: @Rainner please tell me how to solve...thanks

Comment: @JohnJoe Because email is an inherently insecure method of communication. There's also the problem that randomly - generated passwords are difficult to remember; if the user will likely need to change that password, why not use a reset protocol that takes care of that in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice: Undefined index: forgotpassword

You have to make sure the index is the same from android & PHP.

Wrap your code around the following check:

```
if(isset($_POST['forgotpassword'])){//code here}else{//undefined}
```

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

As the error says, a param is missing, which is the connection:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
```

(Add the connection as a 2nd parameter of your db function)

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given

this is because the query failed.to avoid this error, add more checks:

```
if($result){
   $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}else{
   //failed
}
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply ! can  you check my post again?

Comment: @JohnJoe put all the code inside of the if statement, and `forgotpassword` needs to be sent from android, index is case sensitive